# Habilitar link após atualização no Banco de Dados

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou precisando fazer com que o admin da loja virtual após habilitar a loja pelo gerenciador, o link no site seja habilitado automaticamente. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no site quando a loja estiver desabilitada no gerenciador, aparecer a mensagem: Volte em breve. Não saco muito de Jquery, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa parte? A alteração do status está pronta e que foi desenvolvida em PHP e Mysql, seria apenas o link habilitar e desabilitar automaticamente na mudança do status com Jquery. Vale lembrar que a página onde irá alterar o link está em HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.

```
<div id="link"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                atualizar();
           });
           var atualizar = function(){
              $.get('atualizar.php',function(resultado){
                     $('#link').html(resultado);
              });
           setTimeout('atualizar()', 3000);
    }
    </script>
```

atualizar.php

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_habilitada;");
$jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

if($jm->Habilitada == '1'){
  echo "<a href= \"https://loja.sitedocliente.com.br\" class=\"mix-link\" target=\"_blank\">Acessar</a>";
}else{
  echo "<a href= \"#\" class=\"mix-link\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal1\">Acessar</a>";
}
```